# Wordpress vs html page SEO perspective

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, keyword, web-crawler

I know there are more posts like this. None of them seem to answer my question though.

Let's say i have two websites. One is a Wordpress site, the other is a self scripted html site.

Both websites are the same in text and so.

The websites just contain a couple of pages with good keyword-rich text. No fancy things.

If i place both websites online, which one will rank out higher in Google?

PS: I know Wordpress has a lot of fancy plug-ins for SEO. I am not counting these in this equation. People say things like: "Google just likes Wordpress's structure. But a couple of HTML documents are much easier and faster to crawl."

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "People say things like: Google just likes Wordpress's structure. But a couple of HTML documents are much easier and faster to crawl." Are they? Do you work for Google? Have you written a web crawler?

Comment: This is impossible to answer, but I highly doubt Google gives higher ranking to a web page just because they use a certain technology.

Comment: Sorry, i should have used quotes there to avoid confusion.
What i meant to say was: People say things like: "Google just likes Wordpress's structure. But a couple of HTML documents are much easier and faster to crawl."

And no i haven't written a crawler, nor do i know how they work. That's kind of the reason why i am asking this question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be difficult to ascertain which would rank higher without seeing the code of both websites side by side. If you do publish both websites together to test then you will probably be punished for having duplicate content.

- WordPress's HTML structure and semantics have been created with
  accessibility in mind which is what Google would give weight to.
- If you use friendly and relative filenames/URLs as WordPress does,
  this is also a plus.
- If you use simple HTML files as @Paul D. Waite mentions above then
  indeed this will be faster to crawl than dynamic pages like PHP.

I would conclude if your website is relatively simple and you don't need to update it regularly then, a static website would rank better as it's just content and none of the fuss.

Don't forget inbound links will play a big factor in your page rank.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I won't post them side by side, just in theory.
I have recently got a hold of some wordpress sites made by a different company. These websites are in no way dynamic. They are just static informational pages made to rank good in Google by having good keyword rich texts and headings. I didn't see any point for Wordpress since most of the sites exist out of 2 or 3 text pages and 0 posts.

So i thought i would check here if there is something i'm missing.

Comment: Cool. If you do change the website to static HTML make sure you setup some 301 redirects from the old pages until Google re-indexes your new stuff ;-)